# Parsing malformed xml file in Go

Tags: go

I have a large number of xml files to parse that contain unclosed tags wrapped in closed tags. Something like below:

```
<submission>
<first-name>Henry
<last-name>Donald
<id>4224
</submission>
```

I set decoder.Strict = false but it is still unable to parse the entire xml file properly.

```
type Submission struct {
    FirstName string `xml:"first-name"`
    LastName  string `xml:"last-name"`
    ID        string `xml:"id"`
}

func main() {
    dec := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(sub)))
    dec.Strict = false
    dec.AutoClose = xml.HTMLAutoClose
    dec.Entity = xml.HTMLEntity

    var s Submission
    err := dec.Decode(&s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-_chEpDhzX

I know there is a html tokenizer that I may try using but I would prefer to use the XML package as the majority of the files are properly formatted.

Comment: Consider pre-processing your XML files to correct them before passing them to your program.  If they are all malformed in a similar way then it should be pretty easy to correct them.  The general problem is that the XML parser cannot know exactly *how* an instance document is malformed so it can't really guess about how to interpret it loosely (the way you expect it to).

Comment: See [`Decoder.AutoClose`](https://godoc.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder).

Comment: Side note (although this may only be in your simplified example): don't get a reader from a `string` via `bytes.NewReader([]byte(stringVar))`; instead use [`strings.NewReader(stringVar)`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader).

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me, which is probably only ideal if you know the problematic tags. Although, strangely it doesn't work if I also add first-name.

```
dec.AutoClose = append(dec.AutoClose, "last-name")
dec.AutoClose = append(dec.AutoClose, "id")
```

Answer (score -1):

No ways around it. You need your own decoder: http://play.golang.org/p/Kr7nq64f-c

Comment: I didn't mention that this example will not work for all examples. You'll need to tweak it if you have additional nested elements.

Comment: (a) You answer isn't entirely true (e.g. `AutoClose` if the set of such tags is known) but more importantly (b) link only answers are not recommend on SE, you should include at least the core of what you link to directly in the answer and (c) your comment probably should have been an edit to the answer.